# Compression unit test data "easy case"

Tags: c++, unit-testing, random, compression

In another post I created a piece of data, which make compressor annoyed.

[Create 'worst case test' data for compression test](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153258/create-worst-case-test-data-for-compression-test)

Now I am trying to make it happy.  I generate another data set, with a lot of duplicated binarys.  Of couse a data set composed of only one value is the best, but that is too easy.

This time I use a random number generator.  Inside a loop, each time either add a new byte or duplicate some bytes until reach a predefined length.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<unsigned char> Data;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> rand(0.0, std::nextafter(1.0, DBL_MAX));

    const unsigned int length = 0x10000; // file minimal size

    Data data;
    data.reserve(length * 2);
    while (data.size() < length)
    {
        if (data.size() <= 1 || rand(mt) < 0.5)
        {
            // add a new byte
            data.push_back((unsigned char)(rand(mt) * 256)); 
        }
        else
        {
            // duplicate some bytes
            unsigned int count = (unsigned int)(rand(mt) * (data.size() / 2) + 1);
            data.insert(data.end(), data.end() - count, data.end());
        }
    }

    const char* filename = "c:\\_Test\\easy.dat";
    std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if (ofs.bad() || !ofs.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "fail to open file\n";
        return -1;
    }
    ofs.write((char*)data.data(), data.size());

    std::cout << "job done\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The 7-zip is extremely happy with it.  With 7z format, 90kb data compressed to 900 bytes, and with zip format, it compressed to less than 2kb.

Again any suggestions and help are appreciated.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are using `uniform_real_distribution` instead of `std::uniform_int_distribution` and cast the results to `unsigned char`?

Comment: no special reason, just copy from another program for opengl:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

### 1. Don't use C-style casts

Here

```
 data.push_back((unsigned char)(rand(mt) * 256)); 
             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and here

```
 unsigned int count = (unsigned int)(rand(mt) * (data.size() / 2) + 1);
                   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

you use (unchecked) C-style cast operations. I C++ all casts should be either checked, or explicitly a `reinterpret_cast` (which is merely the same, but clearly shows intention).

In your cases a `static_cast<unsigned char>` and a `static_cast<unsigned int>` seems to be more appropriate for me.

### 2. If you're dealing with plain integer numbers prefer using `std::uniform_int_distribution`

You are using `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>`

```
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> rand(0.0, std::nextafter(1.0, DBL_MAX));
```

to finally generate integer types (done through implicit conversion).

It would seem more appropriate to use

```
 std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> rand(0, std::nextafter(1, UINT_MAX) /* intentional ?? */ );
```

or even better simply

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> rand();
```

and

```
data.push_back(static_cast<unsigned char>
    (rand(mt) % std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()); 
// ...
unsigned int count = rand(mt) * (data.size() / 2) + 1;
```

Floating point conversions and calculations may cause unnecessary overhead in the emitted assembly instructions.

### 3. Prefer `std::numeric_limits` over the C-style macro definitions

In C++ you should prefer using `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` over the `DBL_MAX` C-style macro.

At least with GCC I always get [compiler errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/217a6cc593b2227d) using these constants (even though `<cstdint>` was included).

### 4. Modularize your code to be resuable

As you tagged this with [unit-testing](/questions/tagged/unit-testing) I would consider to create a little helper library API that can be used with the unit tests, without calling a separate program.

Instead of the `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` entry point, refactor your code (including the stuff from [Create 'worst case test' data for compression test](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153258/create-worst-case-test-data-for-compression-test)) to a helper function API, that can be used easily with the various unit tests:

```
 namespace Test7ZipData {
     int create_worst_compressible_data(const char* filename);
     int create_easily_compressible_data(const char* filename);
     // int create_average_compressible_data(const char* filename); ????
 }
```

Compile these into a library, that will be linked with you unit tests.

### 5. Prefer using raw string literals instead of escaping special characters

Instead of

```
const char* filename = "c:\\_Test\\easy.dat";
```

you can provide a raw string literal

```
const char* filename = R"(c:\_Test\easy.dat)";
```

That enhances readability of the literal text.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This piece code was taken from a unit test project I made, to test several different compression methods, most of them are written in C.  While I am working in a environment of mixing up C and C++, I did not take care to avoid use some C style code.  I will change them.

Comment: @TigerHwang _"most of them are written in C"_ AFAIK the 7zip (LZMA?) core library API operates on the data buffers solely. You could provide your buffers directly, and eliminate the file roundtrip.

Comment: Not 7zip, I only use it to try created file.  They are LZW, b-zip, Huffman, z-lib and so on.  Some are using 3rd party lib, and some are implemented locally.  I must make sure all of them are correctly used, and try to make some of them more efficient.